# How can I implement localization when there is multiple dynamic values in the URL?

Tags: php, laravel, url, url-parameters

[The documentation of laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/localization) says:

> You may also change the active language at runtime using the setLocale method on the App facade:
>
> ```
> Route::get('welcome/{locale}', function ($locale) {
>     App::setLocale($locale);
>
>     //
> });
> ```

Also it says:

> The default language for your application is stored in the `config/app.php` configuration file.

Which means if there isn't any value which specifics the language, then laravel will be used of the default language *(which is defined there)*.

---

Ok well, what about when there is a dynamic value in the URL? I mean how can I detect the language when there either is or isn't  `{locale}` in the URL. For example:

```
 Route::get('post/{locale}/{id}', function ($locale, Request $request) {
     App::setLocale($locale);
     $post_id = $request->segment(2);
     // search in the database based on $post_id
 });
```

As you see, I've got post id of the URL by using `segment(2)`. But it won't work all the time. Because sometimes `{locale}` will not be set *(and we expect laravel uses default language)*. In that case I need to use `segment(1)` to achieve post id.

Anyway, how can I implement *localization* when there is other dynamic values in the URL?

Comment: Is it typo that `Route::get('post/{locale}{id}',` should be as `Route::get('post/{locale}/{id}',`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change your route as:

```
Route::get('post/{id}/{locale?}', function ($id, $locale = null, Request $request) {
   if(! is_null($locale)) {
      App::setLocale($locale);
   }
   $post_id = $id;
   // search in the database based on $post_id
});
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-parameters)

Its called Optional Parameters